# Diablo 2 different maps?

Tags: diablo-ii

I was testing out ATMA to try to change my name on my account (to no success) but now I realized that all my map data is lost, and on top of that my map is completely changed?

my main save's map now: (circled the exit to rogue encampment)

[image]

And this is a dummy save I just made to compare map differences

[image]

I realized that ATMA's most recent version is for 1.11, but on both screens the game states that it's in 1.13 expansion. The map for my main save used to be like the dummy's but now it changed. Is there any possible way to fix this? And can anyone explain to me what happened? I don't think reinstallation will be an option because although I have the registration CD I do not have the key code anymore (thrown out a long time ago, it seems).

Comment: Lemme ask the stupid question - isn't that one of Diablo's biggest features, randomized maps?  This is supposed to be normal behavior in my experience.  Or does ATMA alter that somehow? (a quick glance at a page I can find says that it does not)

Comment: I thought map randomizing to explored areas was only in battle.net worlds, because i know there are mods that randomize maps to give it a "bnet feel".

Comment: @Radhil Maps for single player characters are static unless you take certain actions, which Stephen enumerated in an answer below. This is actually heavily abused in "speedruns" of this game, where you can savescum to get a beneficial map, and then "start over" on that map with a backup save knowing where to go.

Comment: @Strix - Admittedly have played much less of Diablo 2 than most, but I would swear that happened every time I entered the game.  Guess that's something learned, and Stephen got an upvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It used to be that Diablo II would save your single player maps, except in the following situations.  You:

- Join a multiplayer game with the character
- Play a mod (? not certain on this one)
- Change difficulties

It may have changed with a recent (last 5 years or so) patch.  In multiplayer (even if it's only a local multiplayer game) the maps were always randomized.

Comment: This is still correct.  In single player, people will often want to persevere a favorable map for an MF character, like a good Durance of Hate level 2 map where the stairs down to level 3 where Meph is are only a couple of teleports away, to have fast runs.   If you have a good Hell Meph map and you accidentally click Nightmare difficulty, you'll lose the good map that you had.  If you want to change maps to get a better one, then you can intentionally click another difficulty (or start a TCP/IP game) and see if your new map is better.

Answer (score 7):

Unless something drastic is going on with your mods, this is normal behavior for Diablo II.  The map is randomized every time you enter one.  Yes, that can include parts of the base camp, or at least which way the entrance is.

Comment: Alright, although its kind of a big pain to have all your minimap data arbitrarily erased. At least now I know its not ATMA, thanks